# Subsequences and convergence. Do all subsequences have to converge to the same limit for the sequence to be convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was asked this question:

Prove that $a_n$ converges if and only if:

$a_{2n},a_{2n+1},a_{3n}$ all converge

I thought this was an easy generic question until I read the hint which said:
Note: It is not required that the three sub-sequences have the same limit. This needs to be shown

This is what is confusing me because I have found two sources stating something different:

Proposition 4.2. A sequence an converges to L ∈ R if and only if every subsequence converges to L.

and

Let $a_n$ be a real sequence. If the subsequence $a_{2n}$ converges to a real number L and the subsequence $a_{2n+1}$ converges to the same number L, then $a_n$ converges to L as well.

So my question is: for a sequence $a_n$ to converge does it's subsequences have to converge to the same limit? (I suspect not) and if the answer is no can you help me prove why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If a sequence converges its subsequences must converge to the same limit. This follows directly from the definition of the limit of a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

If a sequence has two subsequences that do not both converge to the same limit, then the sequence does not converge.

---

This can be proven using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of convergence:

- Let $a_n$ converge to $L$, and let $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k\to\infty}$  be a subsequence of $a_n$.
- Let $\epsilon > 0$.
- Then, because $a_n$ converges to $L$, there exists some $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $|a_n - L|<\epsilon$.
- Because $n_k$ is an increasing sequence of integers (by definition of a subsequence), there exists such $K$ that $n_K > N$.
- Then, if $k > K$, we have $n_k > n_K > N$, and from the previous point, we get that $|a_{n_k} - L|<\epsilon$, meaning that $a_{n_k}$ converges to $L$.

---

However, your case is special in that there is an overlap of sequences, for example $a_6$ is in the first and third sequence, and $a_9$ is in the second and third sequence. In fact, the third sequence alternates between the first two sequences, and you can use this to prove all three limits must be equal.

Comment: Ok so for $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$ I can say we are either in the odd or the even case and then $a_{3n}$ goes between the two cases.

Comment: @babylon Yup. And that, forces the sequences to converge to the same number. Then you need to prove that the whole sequence also converges to the same number.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word "required" in the hint is confusing. Focus instead on the last sentence:

> Note: It is not required that the three sub-sequences have the same limit. **This needs to be shown**

In other words, *you* need to show that as a result of the given hypotheses, the three sub-sequences *do* have the same limit. You need to do that precisely because it *is* a necessary condition for $a_n$ to converge.